# Indenting Paragraphs For Bullets In A Table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to decrease the indentation on the bulleted paragraphs in even rows in a 2x6 table. I went to "Table Tools" -> "Design" -> "Table Styles" -> "More" -> "New Table Style..." and created a style with negative paragraph indentation on the "even banded rows". Applying the style only affects the first cell of the even rows. I recreated the table and applied the same style. The first cells are affected, as well as two of the second cells.

Why is the style not applying to the correct rows? Also, adding a bullet makes the row unaffected by the indentation. How can I fix this?